# Characterize growth behaviour of functions via derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let us assume we have a monotonically increasing function $f(x)$ of which we want to characterize its growth behavior, that is, does it grow faster than the function $c x^n$ or slower, where c is some positive constant. Let us say the function $\frac{f(x)}{x^n}$ has a positive slope in a particular range $[a,b]$ with $a,b>0$. Can we then conclude that the function $f(x)$ does indeed grow faster than $cx^n$ in that range? I would say yes, because the derivative is
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{f(x)}{x^n} \right)'= \frac{1}{x^n}\left( f'(x) - n\frac{f(x)}{x} \right) >0.
\end{equation}
We thus have $f'(x)> n\frac{f(x)}{x}$. For the derivative of $c x^n$ we find $(cx^n)'=n\frac{cx^n}{x}$. In more general terms, how would one characterize the growth behaviour of a function by just looking at its derivative and how it is related to the original function? Is there some literature out there?

Comment: Do you think "growing faster than $cx^n$" means the same as "growing faster than $x^n$" when $x,c,n$ are all positive? If not, then you need to take $c$ into account

Comment: Yes, I think of it as the same. I'm interested in knowing if this function $f$ behaves more like $cx^n$ or $cx^{n+1}$